# jQuery exist url validation is not working in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-validate

I have used jQuery validation for exist profile-url in my CodeIgniter system. Early it was working fine. But now it's not working I couldn't find the error. Please check the below code and help me to fix it.

HTML code

```
<div class="form-group padbtm20">
    <h5 class="control-label">Profile URL (Optional)</h5>
    <div class="col-lg-12 prflinkdiv">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 leftmargnprofilelink">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="profileurl" minlength="4" maxlength="20" data-msg-required="Please enter your public username">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery code

```
$('form').validate({
rules: {
    password: {
        required: true
        , minlength: 6
        , maxlength: 20
    },
    cfmPassword: {
        equalTo: "#password"
        , required: true
        , minlength: 6
        , maxlength: 20
    },
    profileurl: { 
        remote: {
            url: "http://localhost:8888/codeigniter/edit/username_exists",
            type: "post",
            data:
                {
                    login: function()
                    {
                        return $('input[name="profileurl"]').val();
                    }
                }
             }           
    } 
}, 
messages:{
    profileurl:{ 
        remote: jQuery.validator.format("{0} is already taken. Please try another one")
    }
}
});
```

Controller->Edit.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
    $this->load->model('m_edit'); // load model 
}

function username_exists()
{
   $username = $this->input->post('profileurl');
   $query = $this->m_edit->username_exist($username);
   $status ="true";

   if($query){
       $status = "false";
   }
}
```

Models->M_edit.php

```
function username_exist($username)
{ 
    $this->db->select('prof_link'); 
    $this->db->from('register');
    $this->db->where('prof_link',$username); 

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any `form` tag in the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do **not** need the data object because the value of the `profileurl` field is sent by default...

```
profileurl: { 
    remote: {
        url: "http://localhost:8888/codeigniter/edit/username_exists",
        type: "post"
    }                
}
```

You **must** `echo` a JSON encoded string from the server, `"true"` to pass validation, `"false"` to fail validation, or any other string will fail validation where the string becomes the error message.

```
function username_exists()
{
    $username = $this->input->post('profileurl');
    $query = $this->m_edit->username_exist($username);
    $status = "true";

    if ($query)
    {
        // $status = "false"; // default error message
        $status = $username . " is already taken. Please try another one.";
    }

    echo json_encode($status); // <- tells validation to pass/fail
}
```

Finally, **IF you're using the CSRF security** built into CodeIgniter, then you **must** send the value of the CSRF token along with the value of the field.

```
profileurl: { 
    remote: {
        url: "http://localhost:8888/codeigniter/edit/username_exists",
        type: "post",
        data: {  // MUST send the CSRF Token Value
            'csrftoken': function() {
                return $('input[name="csrftoken"]').val();
            }
        }
    }                
}
```

`'csrftoken'` must match the `name` of your hidden CSRF token field.

Comment: Thanks the code is working. But I would like to know why the error message just display "false" only. Why this message part not working? Please help me to display the error message with input data.
 messages:{
    profileurl:{ 
        remote: jQuery.validator.format("{0} is already taken. Please try another one")
    }
}

Comment: @user7152572, that's the wrong approach.  There is no parameter in this case, so the `{0}` will not be replaced with anything.  As already explained in my answer, if you `echo` a JSON encoded string, validation fails and the string becomes the error message.  In other words, the custom message comes from the server.  See my edited answer.

Comment: I did the custom validation I thought there will be a way to do the custom validation using JS. Anyhow thanks a lot man. Cheers :)